# Javascript if OR

Tags: javascript

I want to make a prompt window ask for a code, I've got that part. 
There is 50+ people accessing this page, I would like to give each person a different code.

```
if (var1 OR var2 OR var3 OR var4) //i want to be able to add as many 'var*; as I want here. Anywhere from 2 - lets say 50.
{
    access = true
}
else
{
    access = false
}
```

Comment: No. What you really want is an array of values.

Comment: And you realize that this would not be secure?

Comment: Btw, don't do authentication/authorisation on the client if this is anything more than a learning exercise.

Comment: In JavaScript `OR` is represented by `||`.

Comment: I realise it would be totally useless and insecure, yes. But I looks cool and me and my friends would like to try it. So long as it isn't a pain or a waist of time for you. @Bergi

Comment: @Tropilac This is wrong approach for that what you need.

Comment: Do you have a list of valid codes and you want to compare user's code with the list to determine access rights?

Answer (score 6):

You should use an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of dynamic options.

```
var options = ["var1", "var2", "var3"];

var access = options.indexOf(comparedValue) > -1;
```

Comment: `var access = options.indexOf(comparedValue) > -1;` Why even use an if. :)

Comment: ES6: `var access = options.includes(comparedValue)` :-)

Comment: Yeah, I overcomplicated it, thanks. @Bergi I'm assuming that he is not familiar with ES6 features and want to have [full browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=includes). BTW: There is already [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39270444/6475535) that uses `includes`.

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov: Given it's just a fun project for his friends he hardly cares about browser support

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for checking every element for a single truthyness.

```
if (my_vars.some(x => x)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You meant a comparison of some value against `x`, right?

Comment: I mean like in the question check `var1 || var2 || var3 ...` with an array of `[var1, var2, var3, ...]`

Comment: Should be `(my_vars.some(x => x == user_var))`

Comment: Can you explain `x=>x` if its fine :) I am not that acquainted with arrow functions.

Comment: i do not see any comparison with a value in the question.

Comment: @sabithpocker, it is the equivalent of `function (x) { return x; }`.

Comment: If user enters say `1` and the array of codes is `[1,2,3]` How would you test if the `code` exists in the `array`? `[1,2,3].some(function(x){ return x;})` always returns `true` as per my understanding. Basically where is the check  against the user input!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
const access = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'].includes(someVar)
```

If `someVar` equals any of the array's values (`'var1'`, `'var2'`, `'var3'`), `access` will be `true`; otherwise it will be `false`.